# how to plot 2d random data with imshow method in python

Tags: python, matplotlib

```
import numpy as np
C=np.random.rand (500)
S=np.random.rand(500)
def function(s,c):
    return s*2+c
dc=[]
for i in range(len(C)):
    dc.append(function(S[i],C[i])
```

I don't know how to imshow the random result with imshow. I want to get the image like this:

[image]

Comment: `S` and `C` are 1d arrays -- how do you want to re-arrange them in order to get a matrix which can be plotted with imshow?

Comment: There is a closing parenthesis missing in your `dc.append` command

Comment: Yes，I want convert them into 2d array and imshow or pcolor it,but If I change S and C  in order and the dc will missing.

Comment: ok, but what should your array size be? 20x25, 10x50,...?

Comment: 20*25 is better

Answer (score 1):

You can convert a `1d`- into a `2d`-array using `np.reshape`. Also, you don't need to do your array arithmetics element-wise -- `numpy` does that for you. The below code hopefully does what you want (it's not quite clear from your question):

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt


C=np.random.rand(500).reshape((20,25))
S=np.random.rand(500).reshape((20,25))

def function(s,c):
    return s*2+c

dc = function(S,C)

plt.imshow(dc)
plt.show()
```

The result looks like this:

[image: result of the given code]

Comment: yes,that is good iead to convert aim array into 2D.I have get it .:) thanks

Answer (score 0):

At a test ,I get the scatter map ,but it not better to show all things.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
def function(C,S):
    return 2*C+S**2
axis=plt.subplot()
Sand=np.random.rand(50)
Clay=np.random.rand(50)
dc=function(C=Clay,S=Sand)
plt.scatter(Clay,Sand,c=dc,cmap='jet')
axis.set_xlabel('Clay')
axis.set_ylabel('Sand')
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lslcb.png)

So I want to show it by other method .Pcolor or imshow is better way to realize it.So I ：

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
axis=plt.subplot()
def function (C,S):
    return 2*C+S**2
axis=plt.subplot()
dc=np.ones(50*50).reshape(50,50)
Sand=np.random.rand(50)
Clay=np.random.rand(50)
Clay_or=sorted(Clay)
Sand_or=sorted(Sand,reverse=True)
for i in range(50):
    for j in range (50):
        result=function(Clay_or[i],Sand_or[j])
        dc[j][i]=result
plt.imshow(dc,cmap='jet',extent=(0,1,0,1))
axis.set_xlabel('Clay')
axis.set_ylabel('Sand')
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J45EY.png)

The result is better .But i have a question,how to set axis ticks if i  use the pcolor function?